# What's the difference between a side chain and a state channel?

Tags: sidechain, state-channels

I hear them almost used interchangeably, and I was wondering what the technical difference is so that I can use the terms correctly.

From my understanding, a sidechain is a subset of a state channel (just an implementation of a blockchain as the channel), but I'm curious if there are any good resources out there.